# Problem solving strategy?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, advice

This question has always bothered me, and I've never had a maths coach to guide me along the way and show me what to do next. Nevertheless, I did make top 50 nationally in my national mathematics olympiad after much hard work and learning obscure techniques and theorems of the type that would only come up on an olympiad (vieta jumping, muirhead's, and so on).

However, I still feel as if I can't solve hard problems. I can solve problems where a bit of working or checking of special cases leads the way (e.g. checking a few values and then inducting, or something similar; in fact, one of the problems I solved in the national olympiad I had seen before on artofproblemsolving), though I have never (except once or twice, on my really good days) been able to crack a hard IMO problem (say), where you need many steps to make progress.

It seems as if I can't do independent research for too long (a good skill to have with hard problems), so I cannot march into the unknown like some people do. It seems a god-given gift to be able to do this; many famous mathematicians and scientists have extremely insightful and elegent papers they wrote only when still teenagers, e.g. James Clerk Maxwell's "Oval curves" paper when he was 14, or Gauss's legendary investigations into number theory at just 19! I'm 18 now.

What can I do to become an explorer? I see IMO winners as magicians; they can paint beautiful pictures with the theorems that I know, whereas I can only use them in the prototypical situations. My background is slightly lacking in some areas, but I know this isn't what's holding me back (unless someone can convince me that learning new theorems will somehow increase my problem solving creativity, which I highly doubt).

I'm at a stage now where I need to decide between doing loads of problems that are above my head, and persevering even if I don't have any insight within hours, persevering until I discover a new method or technique by myself, and keep on doing it until I master problem solving. On the other hand, I can keep learning more new techniques and use THOSE to solve hard problems. I could also keep looking at solutions and giving up after only a few hours, until I accumulate a whole database of tricks and shortcuts which I can use to solve ever harder problems, without ever increasing my "natural" problem solving ability.

I don't want this. I want to feel like I am a master problem solver who can solve NEW problems that I have never seen anything like before.

Please help me decide what to do. Thanks!

Comment: It was much easier to do math research at a young age back in the time of Gauss and Maxwell.  What problem solving books have you used?  For example have you read The Art and Craft of Problem Solving?  Do you hang out at artofproblemsolving.com?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Terribly sorry for that, I felt like pouring out everything that's been bothering me lately.

Comment: Then I think you're looking for psychoanalysis.stackexchange.com --- we answer math questions here.

Comment: @littleO: I have an aops account which I use sometimes, yes. I have looked into ACoPS and found it on the easy side of olympiad, while problem solving strategies was on the mid-hard side. I can solve most of the early problems in each chapter, but I get lost with the ones which require a bit more thought and perseverance (ones that I haven't seen anything like before), which is exactly my problem.

Comment: The number of problem-solving competitions diminishes rapidly from age 18 on. While a number of very good mathematicians were competitive problem solvers, many were not.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks for the encouragement, but I have heard it all before, and I can't help but think that if someone who was genuinely talented in mathematics (say a future fields medal winner (I know the logical difficulties of using this term, sorry if they annoy you)) tried their best like I currently do at solving IMO problems, they would most definitely make progress. I am not like Grothendiek, who spent his youth getting to the heart of theories, while his other, less talented contemporaries, spent it in drilling olympiad problems. I CANNOT even do that (understand theories deeply).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: This IS a maths question. I should probably rephrase it: How can I understand theories deeply enough in order to better motivate my approaches to tackling problems?

Comment: I feel you are overcomplicating things. Investigate all things that interest you, go for them whole-heartedly, and enjoy the ride.

Comment: I remember a kid, awesomely blazing quick, fell apart on anything a little hard. With a lot of coaching, that got turned around, he ended up with an IMO gold.  I remember another IMO team member, who lost interest in contests, wrote a few papers as an undergraduate, ended up doing what he wanted to do.

Comment: If you wish for an answer, I suggest listening to Gerry and not asking the question in a solid brick of text.  Seriously, it's a quality of life issue, I won't read it in this format and I'm sure most other users won't either.

Comment: I added a tag and spacing.

Comment: What you're asking in essence is quite a broad question; "How do I become creative?". It's a question whose answer a lot of people are after..

Comment: @user45220 Could you please provide any updates on the decisions you've made, their consequences, and your conclusions? I am also struggling with some of the same questions, and I would be very interested if you could share some of what you have learned.

Answer (score 1):

Persistently thinking about the problem, recording every little detail in the thought process, is the only way to get to a point where you can solve IMO 3s and 6s. The tendency is to ask people about how to become a master problem solver but the answer is to patiently climb the steep mountain of solving tough IMO problems even if it means that you have to think for weeks together about it.

Just as a matter of information, I used to ask the exact same questions. I then stopped asking, and started thinking about IMO 3s and 6s. I could very gradually solve some and it took almost 4 years to get to this point (I am 35 years old now).